# What does "level of douchery" stand for?

Tags: vocabulary

I was reading an article about the language use in specific area of the States. Can anyone explain what is the "level of douchery"?

This whole sentence is

> Something is reaching a whole new level of douchery

Comment: Please use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Douchery](http://www.yourdictionary.com/douchery) is a slang vulgar term that indicates ignorance and rude behaviour. In the context you are referring to the author is probably saying that the level of ignorance and incorrect/vulgar usage of the language is increasing consistently:

> - (slang, vulgar) Behaviour that is rude, obnoxious, ignorant, or foolish.

Source: www.yourdictionary.com

Comment: When something reaches a "whole new level", it has not just increased, but increased by a large magnitude.

Comment: Yes, unluckily this aspect  is increasing consistently.